# Qual a diferença entre atribuir e comparar variáveis strings com função ou com operador de atribuição e comparação?

Tags: c, string, operadores

Me deparei com as seguintes perguntas:

- Qual a diferença entre as expressões  `strcpy (s, t)  e  s = t` ?
- Qual a diferença entre as expressões  `if (strcmp (s, t) < 0)  e  if (s < t)` ?

Tentei compilar o código `s=t` da primeira pergunta, mas obtive erro. Entretanto consigo compilar `if (s<t)`, mas percebi pelo seu comportamento que não é semelhante ao comando `strcmp`. O que significa então `if(s<t)`? Sendo que s e t são vetores de `char` (*strings*)?

Os códigos que seguem estavam nas mesmas questões das quais extrair as perguntadas citadas no início e estou postando eles porque servem como uma "ilustração" da pergunta. 
O que há de errado nos segmento de código abaixo?

```
char b[8], a[8];
strcpy (a, "abacate");
strcpy (b, "banana");
if (a < b)
   printf ("%s vem antes de %s no dicionário", a, b);
else
   printf ("%s vem depois de %s no dicionário", a, b);



char *b, *a;
a = "abacate";
b = "banana";
if (a < b)
   printf ("%s vem antes de %s no dicionário", a, b);
else
   printf ("%s vem depois de %s no dicionário", a, b);



char *a, *b;
a = "abacate";
b = "amora";
if (*a < *b)
   printf ("%s vem antes de %s no dicionário", a, b);
else
   printf ("%s vem depois de %s no dicionário", a, b);
```

Comment: Alguém que entende de C poderia melhorar o título desta pergunta? Desse jeito não fica claro a dúvida, mas a pergunta parece interessante.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
strcpy(s, t)
```

Está copiando o conteúdo de `t` em `s`. Esta cópia acontece *byte* a *byte* da *string*. Ou seja, todos os *bytes* que estão presentes no endereço indicado por `t` no final da operação também estarão presentes no endereço indicado por `s`. De qualquer forma prefira usar a função [`strncpy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) que é mais segura.

```
s = t
```

Está copiando o ponteiro contido na variável `t` para a variável `s`. Como é um *array* a operação é inválida. Você está tentando atribuir um tipo `char *` (ponteiro para caractere) que é o tipo de todo literal *string* em C (a grosso modo) para um *array* de caracteres, e são coisas diferentes.

```
if (strcmp(s, t) < 0)
```

Faz a comparação dos *bytes* de `s` com os *bytes* existentes em `t` e analisa há diferenças entre eles e o primeiro caractere diferente tem que ser menor em `s` do que o caractere encontrado na mesma posição em `t`.

```
if (s < t)
```

Está comparando se o valor de onde está o *array* de `s` que é apenas um endereço, é menor que o valor de `t` que também é um endereço de *array*. Como estamos falando de uma sequência de caracteres temos que usar sempre as funções. Nestes casos usar o ponteiro não tem utilidade alguma. [Teste no **ideone**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) como fica errado. Se fizer na ordem alfabética dá certo por coincidência mas se não estiver em ordem dá errado porque a comparação é com o ponteiro e aí a ordem de  alocação é que vale.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Compare.c).

Nos códigos mostrados no final, você consegue atribuir um valor para a variável porque é um ponteiro e não dá erro justamente porque o tipo é compatível com o literal. neste caso funciona porque você só está trabalhando com literais.

Mas estará cometendo um grave erro em outras situações porque não há espaço alocado para estas variáveis. Variáveis ponteiros só guardam o apontador, o endereço de onde estará o objeto. A memória neste endereço deverá ser alocada através da função [`malloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc). E depois deve ser liberada com `free()`. Esta alocação retornará o endereço de onde a memória foi alocada e é seu ponteiro. No seu exemplo funciona, porque o literal foi alocado pelo compilador e este endereço foi usado. Se você tentar alterar este conteúdo, terá problemas.

O último exemplo começa ir pelo caminho certo porque ao invés de comparar os ponteiros, ele compara o conteúdo, já que o operador `*` indica para pegar pegar o valor existente no endereço apontado pela variável. O único problema é que esta comparação ocorre apenas no primeiro caractere da *string*. A comparação desta forma é basicamente numérica, ela não é feita na sequência de caracteres. O computador não consegue percorrer a sequência por conta própria, é necessário um algoritmo que faça isto. E neste caso a operação só estaria correta se comparasse toda a *string*, e isto é feito com a já conhecida `strcmp()`.

Answer (score 5):

Como um vetor é um elemento que ocupa posições contíguas na memória RAM, basta guardar o endereço de memória da primeira posição do mesmo. O restante pode ser obtido por aritmética básica com ponteiros, veja:

Para este exemplo considere a seguinte variável **char b[8]**.

Portanto:

```
b[1] = 'c';
```

é o mesmo que fazer:

```
*(b+1) = 'c';
```

O segundo caso, inicialmente, pode parecer estranho, mas o que está sendo feito é bem simples.

(1+b) significa deslocar 1 byte de memória a partir do início do vetor (armazenado no ponteiro **b**). O resultado de (b+1) é um ponteiro (um endereço de memória) da posição 1 do vetor (o mesmo que b[1]). Para colocar um valor nessa posição, é preciso utilizar o operador *, com ele pode-se acessar o conteúdo do endereço de memória armazenado no ponteiro. Por isso deve-se fazer *(b+1).

Em outras palavras, (b+1) é a soma de um endereço de memória (guardado pela variável **b**) com 1 byte. Note que é 1 byte, pois se trata de uma variável do tipo char. Se o vetor fosse **int b[10]**, então a soma (b+1) deslocaria 4 bytes (arquitetura 32 bits) a partir do início do vetor. Como C é uma linguagem fortemente tipada, o próprio compilador sabe quantos bytes terá que deslocar (pelo tipo da variável).

Veja outra maneira de fazer o mesmo:

```
char * p;
p = b;
p[1] = 'c';
```

ou

```
char * p;
p = b;
*(p+1) = 'c';
```

O código acima mostra que pode-se atribuir a um ponteiro um vetor de mesmo tipo.

Portanto, uma variável de um vetor em C é, na verdade, um ponteiro para a 1a posição desse vetor e é por essa razão que fazer isso **if (s < t)** não é o mesmo que **if (strcmp (s, t) < 0)**. No primeiro caso está sendo comparado o endereço de memória de **s** e **t**. No segundo caso, está sendo utilizada uma função que itera (byte a byte) sobre esses dois vetores de maneira a comparar se um é igual ao outro em relação aos bytes armazenados.