# Alocação de memória para ponteiros

Tags: c, ponteiro, alocação

Estive lendo e estudando sobre ponteiros e me deparei com a seguinte citação em um livro:
"Embora seja possível utilizá-los como vetores, os ponteiros não possuem memória própria. Só se pode utilizar o endereçamento através de um ponteiro depois que este está apontando para algum objeto já existente."

Entretanto fiquei com algumas dúvidas:
O que significa dizer que os ponteiros não possuem memória própria? Se eles não possuem memória própria onde então estão alocados?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O ponteiro é uma variável como outra qualquer, porém, ele armazena um endereço de memória que referencia outro lugar de memória onde está o conteúdo.

Exemplos:

em C:

```
int * a = malloc(10 * sizeof *a);
```

em C++:

```
int * a = new int[10];
```

a variável **a** é um ponteiro que guarda o endereço de memória para a 1a posição do vetor. O restante das posições são acessadas por meio de aritmética básica, ver essa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80097/3084

Ponteiros possuem 4 bytes numa arquitetura 32 bits e 8 bytes em uma arquitetura 64 bits. Note que eles sempre terão o mesmo tamanho, não importa o tipo de variável que eles apontam. Assim, um ponteiro pra char tem o mesmo tamanho que um ponteiro pra double.

Considerando uma arquitetura de 32 bits, no exempo acima, a variável **a** é um ponteiro de 4 bytes apontando para um vetor que usa 10*4 = 40 bytes de memória RAM (um **int** numa arquitetura 32 bits também usa 4 bytes de memória para ser representado).

**Atualização**

Mesmo quando você apenas declara o ponteiro (sem apontá-lo para nenhum endereço de memória), como abaixo:

```
int * a;
```

os mesmos 4 bytes da RAM são utilizados. Porém, nesse caso, o vetor está apontando para um endereço de memória aleatório.

o mesmo acontece se você fizer assim:

```
int * a = NULL;
```

porém, nesse caso, o vetor está apotando para o endereço 0.

Enfim, os 4 bytes de memória são gastos de qualquer maneira.

Comment: A sintaxe apresentada não é C. Acho que querias dizer `int *a = malloc(10 * sizeof *a);`

Comment: Obrigado @pmg. Fiz a inclusão dos dois exemplos.

Comment: @pmg, editei. Troquei sizeof *a (conforme sua edicao), para sizeof(int). Nesse caso, deve-se pegar o sizeof(int) e multiplicar por 10.

Comment: Hmmm ... `*a` tem tipo `int`, portanto tanto `sizeof *a` como `sizeof (int)` estão correctos. Eu prefiro usar o objecto propriamente dito para, em caso de mudar o tipo, só precisar alterar o código num sítio: `double *a = malloc(10 * sizeof *a);` vs `double *a = malloc(10 * sizeof (double));`

Comment: Ahh tá! Tem razão! Realmente evita duas mudanças. Vou alterar. Obrigado novamente.

Comment: Só precisa ficar claro que este consumo dos 4 bytes (8 em arquiteturas de 64 bits) é relativo. Há consumo mas não alocação direta. Se for no *stack* isto já está alocado. Se for em uma área do *heap*, ela já foi alocada pelo objeto que o contém.

Comment: Obrigado @bigown, cheguei até a começar a escrever a área da memória em que geralmente o ponteiro é armazenado (stack), mas acho que merece ser melhor explorado e não terei tempo agora. Assim que tiver um tempo atualizo sim.

Answer (score 5):

O livro em questão induz em erro.

Os ponteiros são objectos que precisam de espaço de armazenamento tal qual objectos de tipo "normal".

Comment: Juro que não entendi o que você disse

Comment: @Luiz Vê a [definição de *objecto* no Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.15) (a tradução é minha) "região de armazenamento de dados cujo conteúdo representa valores". **Os ponteiros são objectos.** A citação do livro ("os ponteiros não possuem memória própria") induz em erro.

Answer (score 2):

Na verdade o que o autor tentou dizer é que em um ponteiro não é possível armazenar um valor de um tipo inteiro, caractere, real... porque na verdade um ponteiro tem um espaço na memória, mas para armazenar o endereço(de memória) de um objeto alocado, este objeto sim pode receber tipos comuns.

Answer (score -1):

Na verdade ele possui, mas não é bem como os outros objetos.

Imagine a memoria como um todo, muitos e muitos bytes lá. O ponteiro nada mais é que apenas um desses bytes com um valor lá, e esse valor nada mais é que um endereço de memoria. Exatamente como se ele estivesse apontando para um outro lugar.

Os ponteiros em si não são os objetos, os objetos são para onde ele aponta. Ele aponta para a primeira posição da area de memória. Para acessar as seguintes é bem fácil, temos o endereço da primeira posição... Se vc sabe o tamanho do objeto(ex:20) e o vetor aponta pra primeira posição de memória ocupada pelo objeto(ex:um numero inteiro positivo entre 0~2{elevado a alguma coisa}) somando mais um nesse espaço, obtem-se o proximo ex:

```
auto main() -> int
{
    int[10] arr = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int * arr_prt = arr; // arr em si ja é um ponteiro, por isso é possivel 
                         // essa atribuição
    arr[5] = 7;   //<-isso 
                  //é equivalente
    *(arr_prt+5) = 7 //<-isso
}
```

Comment: Os ponteiros em si **são** objectos. O código apresentado não é C. Em C, um array **não** é um ponteiro.