# Problema com entrada no laço comparando string

Tags: c, string, comparação

Não consigo fazer para que entre no laço usando somente a `char` `'Anunciar'`, quando se coloca qualquer coisa, já inicia o laço. O que devo fazer?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char nome[50], op;
    int sexo, passatempo, musica, filme, auto_declara;

    printf("Ola, seja bem-vindo ao Colega de Quarto, como voce se chama ? ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", &nome);
    printf("O que voce deseja, %s ?\n\n", nome);
    printf("---Anunciar---\n\n");
    printf("---Procurar---\n\n");
    scanf("%s", &op);

    do
    {
        printf("\nFormule seu perfil de acordo com as opcoes abaixo: \n");

        printf("\n");

        printf("---Sexo---\n");
        printf("1 - Masculino\n");
        printf("2 - Feminino\n");
        scanf("%d", &sexo);

        printf("\n");

        printf("---Hobby---\n");
        printf("1 - Ler\n");
        printf("2 - Praticar esportes\n");
        printf("3 - Festar\n");
        scanf("%d", &passatempo);

        printf("\n");

        printf("---Gosto Musical---\n");
        printf("1 - Rock\n");
        printf("2 - Funk\n");
        printf("3 - Sertanejo\n");
        printf("4 - Rap\n");
        scanf("%d", &musica);

        printf("\n");

        printf("---Tipo de Filme---\n");
        printf("1 - Acao\n");
        printf("2 - Suspense\n");
        printf("3 - Terror\n");
        printf("4 - Drama\n");
        printf("5 - Comedia\n");
        printf("6 - Ficcao Cientifica\n");
        scanf("%d", &filme);

        printf("\n");

        printf("---Voce se autodeclara ?---\n");
        printf("1 - Preguicosa\n");
        printf("2 - Prestativa\n");
        printf("3 - Caseira\n");
        printf("4 - Festeira\n");
        scanf("%d", &auto_declara);

    } while(op == 'Anunciar');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você declarou sua variável op como comportando um único caractere mas tenta ler uma string para dentro dela e ainda por cima faz uma comparação no while misturando caractere com uma string mas utilizando o delimitador de caractere (um único, entre ') e não de string (entre "). Além disso para comparar strings você precisa utilizar a função strcmp de <string.h> e não o operador ==.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O motivo principal é que você está tentando comparar *strings* com o `==` quando o certo é usar a função [`strcmp()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80074/101). E ainda tem outro problema que não está exatamente comparando duas *strings*, um dos operando é um caractere mal formado, porque o uso de aspas simples indica que você tem **um** caractere, e não uma sequência deles, então o resto será ignorado, então o correto seria:

```
strcmp(op, "Anunciar")
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/StrCmp.c).

[Mais detalhes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80074/101).

Mas ainda isto pode funcionar sem ser o jeito correto de fazer isto pela experiência do usuário. Curiosamente fez certo no miolo do código e errou no que mais precisava montar menus com números da opção. Então a solução de verdade é numerar as opções do menu e comprar o número, se manter *string* assim muita coisa pode dar errada, mesmo que esteja funcionando (compilando e executando).